# Django sum object data by date of highest occurrence

Tags: django, django-views, django-filter

Say I have a fruit shop. I sell Apples, Bananas and other Fruit.

Sometimes I sell several items in one hour, sometimes none.

I would like to know which date I sold the most apples and how many I sold that day...

(I'm using a sqlite3 database with django 1.5)

My model looks like:

```
class fruitsales(models.Model):
    fruit = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    num_sold = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.fruit
```

An exhaustive data set could look like:

```
fruit = "apple", num_sold = 3, date = 01/01/2015
fruit = "apple", num_sold = 5, date = 01/01/2015
fruit = "banana", num_sold = 24, date = 01/01/2015
fruit = "apple", num_sold = 6, date = 02/01/2015
```

I'm currently doing something like this in my views.py:

```
fruit = fruitData.objects.filter(fruitName=fruit***This is from the url and would in this
instance be:"apple"***).values('fruit').annotate(total_Sold=Sum('num_sold'))
```

This returns; apple, 14, 02/01/2015. whereas I'm hoping for; apple, 8, 01/01/2015

Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you. **This code is not tested**

Try this:

```
fruitData.objects.filter(...).values('date').distinct().annotate(total_sold=Sum('num_sold')).values('fruit', 'total_sold')
```

Comment: This gets me quite some way, it aggregates every type of fruit sold per day, so in our example, it's giving apple, 8, 01/01/2015 and apple, 6 02/01/2015. So for the complete query, I guess we'll need a filter on the end. Unfortunately sticking:    .order_by('-mentions')[:1]  on the end results in an error :/ ? Thanks for your assistance Gocht!

Comment: @William  I think that gives you an error because with values, you have a dictionary, not a queryset, try removing the last values.

Comment: Thanks @Gocht, my apologies for not making more clear in the question, but that's where I was struggling to begin with - hence the question ;)

Comment: If order_by is still the error, you could use order_by before the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
fruit = fruitData.objects.filter(fruitName='apple') \
                         .values('fruit', 'date') \
                         .annotate(total_sold=Sum('num_sold'))
```

Comment: This is great, and almost gets me there (gives the aggregated sold per day). Sadly it doesn't return the highest date, but rather all the dates. I'm struggling to limit the result to just the max.

Comment: Sorry didn't read your post carefully, what if you change your `Sum` to `Max`? You need to `from django.db.models import Max`.

Comment: it looks like this is returning the max number sold per day (per given fruit), so rather than returning just the one row: "apple", 01/01/2015, ***from 8 sold***.   It is returning two rows: "apple", 01/01/2015, ***from 5 sold*** and "apple", 02/01/2015, ***from 6 sold***

Comment: I'm confused with your schema, you need to show us your model code.

Comment: Thanks Shang, I've added to my question :)